# rewrite query to be more efficient

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Hi I'm looking to rewrite this query because currently it looks pretty bad. Basically I have a table in my DB that looks like this:

```
Dt            QKey      QDisplay
12/31/2019    201904    Qtr 04
12/30/2019    201904    Qtr 04
.....
10/01/2019    201904    Qtr 04
```

This table is populated with 4 quaterts, and in the DT column you would have a date for every single date. I only tried to show relevant data.
I'm looking to select the MIN and MAX date based on the QKey which is derived from this query:

```
 SELECT DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
```

This query gives me first day of Quarter 4, but I want to go against my table and grab a bunch of data which is why I'm using the table to begin with.

My current query looks like this:

```
 SELECT MIN(Dt)'FROM', MAX(Dt)'TO',QKey,QDisplay 
 FROM tbl1
 WHERE QKey = (SELECT QKey 
    FROM tbl1
    WHERE Dt = (SELECT DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)))
 Group By Qkey, QDisplay
```

Desired end result:

```
FROM                 TO                Qkey          QDisplay
2019-10-01           2019-12-31        201904        Qtr 04
```

Comment: You should write a syntactically correct query that will run, before focusing on performance.  The columns `QKey` and `QDisplay` will cause your query to break, becasue they are not being aggregated.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes I forgot Group By. I copied it over my SSMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is more simply written as:

```
 SELECT MIN(Dt) as [FROM], MAX(Dt) as [TO], QKey, QDisplay 
 FROM tbl1
 WHERE QKey = (SELECT QKey 
               FROM tbl1
               WHERE Dt = DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(quarter, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0))
              );
```

Then you want to do something about the syntax error on `QKey` and `QDisplay`.

And for this you want indexes on `tbl1(dt, qkey)` and `tbl1(qkey, dt, display